# How to setup client certificate authentication on Jboss As 7

Tags: authentication, certificate, client, jboss7.x, openshift

I have a Jboss AS 7 application running on openshift, i was able to configure Client Certificate Authentication on my local Jboss AS 7 and i will wish to transfer this configurations to my app running on openshift but am unable.

Any help will be greatly be appreciated

Comment: What issues are you running into? What have you tried so far?  What errors did you get?

Comment: I can achieve client certificate auth on my Jboss running on openshift